# Function Template not working, getting error "No suitable user-defined conversion"

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to use a container (`std::vector`, `std::list`, `std::map`, etc...) on a function template but I keep getting an error saying "No suitable user-defined conversion exists"

I tried making a different function template, `print_container()` with 1 argument, and it works.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
using Iterator = typename T::iterator;

template<typename C, typename V>
std::vector<Iterator<C>> find_all(C& container, V value) {
    std::vector<Iterator<C>> res;
    for (auto p = container.begin(); p != container.end(); ++p)
        if ((*p) == value)
            res.push_back(p);
    return res;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
    std::vector<Iterator<int>> res = find_all(vec1, 1); // does not work
    return 0;
}
```

`find_all()` should return a `std::vector` of iterators with only 1 iterator, the iterator attached to `vec1[0]` and assign that vector to `res`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the returned type

```
std::vector<Iterator<int>> res = find_all(vec1, 1);
//...................^^^ wrong
```

From that call you obtain a vector of iterators of `std::vector<int>`, not of `int`

```
std::vector<Iterator<std::vector<int>>> res = find_all(vec1, 1);
//...................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  correct
```

To avoid this sort of problems, usually you can use `auto` (starting from C++11)

```
auto res = find_all(vec1, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

The return type is `std::vector<Iterator<std::vector<int>>>`, not `std::vector<Iterator<int>>`.

```
std::vector<Iterator<std::vector<int>>> res = find_all(vec1, 1);
```

Use of `auto` is better for cases like this.

```
auto res = find_all(vec1, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The template argument of the Iterator in this declaration

```
std::vector<Iterator<int>> res = find_all(v, 1);
```

Is invalid. The type `int` has no iterators. See this alias declaration

```
template<typename T>
using Iterator = typename T::iterator;
```

You should write either

```
std::vector<Iterator<std::vector<int>>> res = find_all(v, 1);
```

or

```
auto res = find_all(v, 1);
```